# How to bind a content to specific tab id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to bind a html page inside the tab using jquery. I have wrote the below coding. I didn't get any error but when I click the tab , the page is empty.

**.cshtml page**

```
<div id="my_form" style="width: 1178px; height: 100%; padding: 0px 10px;">
<div id="QuestionTab" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="stepOneQues" href="#Question1">"Q1"</a></li>
            <li><a id="stepTwoQues" href="#Question2">"Q2"</a></li>
            <li><a id="stepThreeQues" href="#Question3">"Q3"</a></li>
        </ul>

 <div id="Question1" style="height: 95%">
                            <h2>tab2</h2>
                        </div>

 <div id="Question2" style="height: 95%">
                            <h2>tab2</h2>
                        </div>

 <div id="Question3" style="height: 95%">
                            <h2>tab2</h2>
                        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script.js**

```
$.ajax({
                url: xxxxxx,
                type: 'POST',
                data: "12345",
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (successMsg) {
                    $('#Question3', container).html(successMsg);
                },
                error: function () {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
```

I am trying to bind the content in the 3rd tab. Since I am newbie to this jquery stuff I couldn't figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What is the container variable you're using in your call to $?
Do you have try to do

```
$('#Question3').html(successMsg);
```

Are you sure your ajax call is actually working/ responding with some data?

Comment: that container variable is to point which container this should get mapped. The ajax call is giving the html page. I have verified it in the network tab.

Comment: @Axnyff- I am just looking whether I need to give all the div names in the like follows, `(#my_form.QuestionTab.Question3)`